# How to group the codes which is inside parenthesis separated together as one unit in java

Tags: java

I have the following sentence:

> "these were: s1, which has the a domain active site mutated to agha;
>   s2, which has the a domain active site mutated to agha; and bm, which
>   has three point mutations (i272a, d346a and d348a) within the b domain
>   that prevent substrate binding [15]."

My objective is to get the codes between parenthesis as a group, which is the following:

```
(i272a, d346a and d348a)
```

So how i can do that using any other way in java with having a consideration that those codes could be separated by conjunctions such as "and" or "or"?

The expected result should look like this as it is stored in a map:

```
index=27 , value=i272a
index=37 , value=d346a
index=47 , value=d348a
```

note: the index is not the right index where the code starts from in the sentence.

Comment: So you have the given text as a String and want to extract the three given value from it?

Comment: Try regex. It should do the job.

Comment: @StefanDollase yes that's exactly what i am looking for, if you could please tell the name of the method with one example, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As spgodara already said, you can solve this problem using a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). In Java, you can use the class [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for this. To better understand regular expressions in Java, have a look at the website [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html). Here is an example how to solve your problem:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexExample {
    private static Pattern outerPattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\(]*(\\([^\\)]*\\))[^\\(]*");
    private static Pattern innerPatter = Pattern.compile("\\(([^\\s\\),]+)|,\\s+([^\\s\\),]+)|([^\\s\\),]+)\\)");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<String>> outerResult = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        String input = "foo (a1, a2, a3, a4 and a5) bar (b1, b2 and b3) more (c1 or c2) ignored (d1, d2) text (e1) the end";
        Matcher outerMatcher = outerPattern.matcher(input);
        while (outerMatcher.find()) {
            outerResult.add(processOuter(outerMatcher));
        }
        System.out.println(outerResult);
    }

    private static List<String> processOuter(Matcher outerMatcher) {
        List<String> innerResult = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher innerMatcher = innerPatter.matcher(outerMatcher.group(1));
        while (innerMatcher.find()) {
            innerResult.add(processInner(innerMatcher));
        }
        return innerResult;
    }

    private static String processInner(Matcher innerMatcher) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= innerMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            String group = innerMatcher.group(i);
            if (group != null) {
                return group;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5], [b1, b2, b3], [c1, c2], [d1, d2], [e1]]
```

Also, use these links to better understand the example above:

- [outerPattern on RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRirqaEUDA/index.html)
- [innerPattern on RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRiIv58UDA/index.html)

Note however, that you might need to adjust the regex to really match your use case.

Answer (score 0):

use this simple regex pattern;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((i\\d+\\w),\\s(d\\d+\\w)\\s\\w+\\s(d\\d+\\w)");

The Output is as follows

i272a

d346a

d348a.

i hope this helps. If you want the full program, you can request for it.Would be glad to give it to you